# rabbitmq with ha req/reply

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy

i have the following scenario which i want to fulfill:

- rabbit mq must be loadbalanced (is it something which is provided by rabbitmq out of the box OR something like haproxy load balancer would work great. Which one is well loadbalanced.)
- CAN haproxy directly push messages to rabbitmq (lets say a POST request coming to http://localhost:3333/redirectToRabbit gets redirected to rabbit  and optionally either the ACK or RESPONSE goes back to client. Also note haproxy would load balance the request)
- with HA; what the best configuration ( exchange with durable queue, durable queue or something else. NOTE: How would the messages gets redirected to some other rabbitmq instance if one of the rabbitmq instance goes down -- persisted and auto redirection to available rabbitmq )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you setup a two-node RabbitMQ cluster. Before talking about ha proxy, you need to understand the [ha policies and the behavior of ha queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) first. Different ha options might cause completely different behaviors of RabbitMQ message replication and node failover. RabbitMQ is so flexible, so don't expect a golden way of configuration which could meet all scenarios.

Then, since you have two nodes which could accept connections, your client could either use a loadbalancer (such as ha proxy) or to use a client driver which supports connecting to multiple nodes of a cluster. Either way will work.

When using haproxy, you have one load balancer ip. Client connects only to this load balancer ip, the load balancer forward you connection to the underlying nodes. But as long as a connection created, the client connection instance keeps talking to one of the node. When one of the node is down, if no "Health Checking" options are configured in your load balancer, client might get random connection failures. When you have "[Health Checking](https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/healthchecks.html)" options configured correctly, the load balancer knows which nodes are down, so that clients will only connect to healthy nodes, which solves the issue.

When not using a load balancer and only base on client driver to connect to all the nodes, the client driver should be able to handle connection failure or health check internally and do failover/retry, etc, to ensure connections go to healthy nodes.

Comment: thanks, one part of the question.. can client/service send message to rabbitmq (without the need of intermediate service actually pushing to rabbitmq ) ? also if rabbitmq with authentication ,, will be better ?

Comment: yes, nothing wrong if rabbitmq is exposed to even internet and a client app connects to it and sends messages to it directly. RabbitMQ has build-in permission control features, you always need to specify username/password when connect to it. So authentication is always required.

Comment: ha proxies tcp level connections and traffic while authentication of RabbitMQ is application level data verification. So even when using user/pass, ha is kind of transparent to clients, just like you are connecting to the underlying nodes.

Comment: right, my question was if a client is connecting ,, i don't want to share the rabiitmq auth .. can haproxy add the auth for me .. if possible.. like some http headers which rabbitmq understands.

Comment: No, ha cannot. And why do you want to do that? If it could and you do that, then any client could connect to RabbitMQ without user/pass via it, sounds wired. If you really don't want your client to specify user/pass, you could leave it "not specified", most RabbitMQ client drivers will use the "guest/guest" default user/pass when connecting then.